# Slow insert to MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, performance, insert, mariadb

I am need transfer data from 10.5.15-MariaDB-0+deb11u1 to Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU16) (KB5011644) - 15.0.4223.1 (X64). I have egine connect installed in MariaDB + unix ODBC driver for MS SQL. And I have created these tables (for remote access to MS SQL):

```
CREATE TABLE `Tabxxx`
ENGINE = CONNECT
TABLE_TYPE = ODBC
BLOCK_SIZE = 10000
CONNECTION='DSN=MSSQL;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx'
TABNAME='DTB_INTERCHANGE.dbo.Tabxxx'
CHARSET = utf8
OPTION_LIST = 'Memory=2'
DATA_CHARSET = utf8;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `ExternCommand` (
  `cmd` VARCHAR(21000) NOT NULL flag=0,
  `number` INT(5) NOT NULL flag=1,
  `message` VARCHAR(255) flag=2)
ENGINE = CONNECT
TABLE_TYPE = ODBC
CONNECTION='DSN=MSSQL;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx'
CHARSET = utf8
BLOCK_SIZE = 1
OPTION_LIST='Execsrc=1';
```

If I am inserting data over this command (Tabyyy is local table in MariaDB):

```
INSERT INTO `Tabxxx` SELECT * FROM `Tabyyy` WHERE ID < 100;
```

the command above is execution speed much slower than:

```
SELECT * FROM `ExternCommand` WHERE `cmd` = " ... "
```

where ... represents text of type `INSERT INTO Tabxx VALUES(...),(...)...`, where is the same data as in table Tabyyy for ID < 100.

Can someone explain why this is? How can you speed up the transfer of approx. 500,000 rows from MariaDB to MS SQL?

Comment: Use a linked server in MSSQL, then just do `INSERT YourTable WUTH (TABLOCKX) (columns) SELECT columns FROM linkedservername.database.schema.table`

Comment: Thanks for the idea, this is what I thought too, but surely it will be faster?

Comment: Surely *what* will be faster? This is one of the fastest methods I can think of

Comment: Verified, the fastest is to create the linked server connection to external server and using SQL above. 500 000 rows is insertet over 7 s. (Note: severs connect is realized over VPN tunnel over Internet, i.e. the servers are in different cities)

Answer (score 0):

The fastest method is probably to use a linked server. You can set this up in SSMS.

Then just do

```sql
INSERT YourTable WITH (TABLOCKX)
(columns)
SELECT columns
FROM linkedservername.database.schema.table;
```

If you can add a `WITH (TABLOCK)` hint to the linked server table also then that will also increase performance, at the cost of locking up that whole table against writes.